# Can't locate element of logging bar in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I need to log into a website by using Selenium. At first when I load the page, there is a button 'log in or register' and it gets clicked with no problems. After that a log in bar appears and I have to send email or phone number. But when I try to find_element of that log bar in code an error appears.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="phone-or-email-login"]"}
```

This is a so simple task, but I've been struggling with this for a few hours now. I've been trying to find the element by XPATH and CSS_SELECTOR, but neither worked. Also as shown in the code I've tried
WebDriverWait with EC.element_to_be_clickable but to no avail.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Exgjt.png)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import time


s = Service('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
browser.maximize_window()
url = 'https://www.rutube.ru'
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
browser.delete_all_cookies()
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/header/section[2]/div[4]/button').click()
time.sleep(10)

browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="phone-or-email-login"]').send_keys('test')
# WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="phone-or-email-login"]'))).send_keys('test')

time.sleep(20)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you notice below, your desired element is wrapped within an `IFRAME`, in such situation you need to switch into the `IFRAME` and then perform `click()`

[image]

Full working code for your reference:

```
# URL
url = "https://rutube.ru/"

# Initialize the Chrome driver and launch url
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get(url)

# create wait object
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 60)
# click on log in or register button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Вход и регистрация']"))).click()
# switch into the iframe
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "snake-popup")))
# perform send keys operation
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "phone-or-email-login"))).send_keys("123")
# below line comesout of iframe context
browser.switch_to.default_content()
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you! I didn't know before about the Iframe things.